# How to check if this is a visitors first visit Laravel Updated

Tags: php, laravel, controller, middleware

I am making a test crypto wallet and I would like my index to redirect to the key setup if this is their first visit currently I have sessions database set up with a boolean for the first visit with a default value of true that is changed to false when the page loads I have tried using middleware one that runs before loading as below:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){
(session('first_visit') ? session(['first_visit => 'false']) : session(['first_visit' => 
'true']));
return $next($request);
```

and one that loads after the page does that's set up like this:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){
$responce = $next($request);
session(['first_visit' => 'false']);
return $responce;
```

in my controller, I've done this:

```
public function first_visit(Request $request){
    return view('welcome', ['first_visit' => session('first_visit')]);
 }
```

I installed debugbar and I see this array under requests:

```
array:5 [▼
"first_visit" => "false"
"_token" => "9rKGFbTm5WeSYJFBw25L8DQZ6ofb8I9grdWg48BZ"
"_previous" => array:1 [▶]
"_flash" => array:2 [▶]
"PHPDEBUGBAR_STACK_DATA" => []
```

]

inside my welcome.blade.php file I have @if($first_visit) then the code for the first visit page with @else for the usual homepage code I am always shown what's inside the if statement unless I put @if(!$first_visit) there's no requests listed to set first_visit from the page what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I have changed the code as the comment still having an issue after setup and displaying the homepage code within the else statement it defaults back to true and I see the first visit page again question now would be is my statement at fault or is it because the default value is true?

Comment: Try to change `session(['first_visit' => 'false']);` to `session(['first_visit' => false]);` it seems that the false is treated as string which result as if condition to be true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if this is a visitors first visit Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67880592/how-to-check-if-this-is-a-visitors-first-visit-laravel)

Comment: That's my first question so unfortunately not

Comment: you define your middleware in `$routeMiddleware` in `Kernel.php` right? then move it to `$middlewareGroups['web']`

Comment: Under $middleware so it's global